# Why isn't Tasker activating Profile?

Tags: tasker

I have created a profile with Tasker to accomplish a simple function, activate WiFi every 10 minutes and if the phone connects to a network leave WiFi on, otherwise turn it off and scan again in 10 minutes. This is my setup:

[image: Profile] [image: Task]
[Profile Big](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zcjtk4jtpe12r3u/Screenshot_2012-11-26-16-36-03.png/) / [Task Big](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2i6i4eurieelh4a/Screenshot_2012-11-26-16-36-22.png/)

WiFi Scan profile never activates (it doesn't get green and the Tasker notification says "no Active Profile"). When I activate Tasker it turns off my WiFi but never turns it on again. It is very strange; is it a Tasker bug? I am running Android 4.1.2 on a Galaxy S2.

Comment: Did you check the 4th tab (variables) what the %WIFI is set to?

Comment: I don't understand. The 4th tab where ? AFAIK %WIFI is a Tasker variable and it is equal to *CONNECTION* when a WiFi connection is established

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While trying to explain where to find that "4th tab", I just see where your problem is:

You use the %WIFI variable to check for a) On/Off and b) the connection mode. Either it is On/Off, or it holds connection info. The first is %WIFI, the other %WIFII:

> **WiFi Info**
>   *%WIFII*
>   When connected to an Access Point (AP), shows human-readable data about the AP. When not connected, show details of the most recent Wifi scan results for nearby APs.
>
> **WiFi Status (dynamic)**
>   %WIFI
>   Whether WiFi is on or off. Note: if WiFi is enabling or disabled, in fact anything but enabled, it's classed as off.

Source: [Tasker UserGuide](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/userguide/en/variables.html)

---

Now back to the original explanation about that "4th tab":

You see some tabs in both pictures. In the first, "Profiles" is selected, in the second "Tasks". In both pictures you see another tab "Scenes". Right to that is one more, "Variables":

[image: Tasker Variables Tab]

But regardless of that: For debugging, you can always to add another item to your task, "Notify", and have it either popup the %WIFI (or whatever variables) content or add it to your notification bar. This is good for debugging.

Comment: Thank you that solved the issue !!! And apparently the profile turns green (on) only once every 5 minutes.

Comment: Glad it solved! The profile turns green when its condition is met -- so 5min is strange, as the only condition is "every 10min". But I never checked how long it stays lit: a) as long as the condition is met, or b) as long as the assigned task is running... You can still play with the timings. Most important thing is: it works ;)

Comment: Sorry I meant 10 minutes :) Thank you very much for your help ;) PD: With %WIFII I can retrieve SSID of the wireless network ?

Comment: Try my debug-hint to find out (use "Notify" to output %WIFII). Spoiler: I'd say so you can -- that and more (connection speed, signal quality, and more; I've used it for a task to automatically switch WiFi off when its signal level gets too low).